# Why Grammarly mask a subheading text as an incomplete sentence?

Tags: sentence

I use Grammarly free account. My strategy to maximize it is to write a sentece by sentence, and see if I get an alert. For example, when I finish writing "John is punched by the monkey" and I get "Passive Voice Misuse" alert, I know I should change that line.

Here is my subheading text, which get "Incomplete Sentences":

"Step 1: Looking for a more simple method"

"Step 2: Measure our chest freezer size"

How do I change those kind of sentences so the alert is not showing up? Thank you.

Comment: Those are not passive verbs, what sort of alert are you getting?

Comment: I am sorry. I will edit the question. Thank you for your question!

Comment: I don't even understand the phrase "passive voice misuse", to be honest. Is it saying that the passive voice is being misused in some way (the passive voice should have a different construction), or is it advising against the use of the passive voice in the first place? The passive voice is a perfectly legitimate writing style, and there is no reason to change it unless there is a good reason for it. (Such as following a company's style guide, or trying to keep things consistent.) Grammarly is pretty famous for *always* proscribing the passive voice.

Comment: Also, Step 2 *is* a a complete sentence. It's an imperative. As for Step 1, change *looking* to *look*. But even that isn't a necessity: most styles don't require titles, headings, or subheadings to be complete sentences.

Comment: @JasonBassford I don't understand too. It is just an alert from Grammarly, and the explanation is only for Premium users. Do you think that will be a problem if I just ignore those kinds of alert?

Comment: @PrabowoMurti You shouldn't be blindly following everything Grammarly says—unless you happen to always agree with it. If there is some guidance you don't think makes sense, ignore it or turn that rule off. What you need to do is understand the reasoning behind the guidance, and then make your own judgment.

Comment: @JasonBassford thank you for your answers, Sir.